# Query return result in SSMS but not in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledb

My database developer gave me a SQL query and it runs successfully in SSMS.

```
USE testdb 

DECLARE @Pipeline TABLE 
  ( 
     pipeline         VARCHAR(4000), 
     unitcode         VARCHAR(4000), 
     designareanumber VARCHAR(4000), 
     nameofnote       VARCHAR(4000) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @Pipeline 
SELECT pipeline, 
       unitcode, 
       designareanumber, 
       nameofnote 
FROM   (SELECT pp.oid               AS OID, 
               nmpp.itemname        AS ItemName, 
               nmpl.itemname        AS Pipeline, 
               tn.trainnumber       AS TrainNumber, 
               uc.unitcode          AS UnitCode,                  

        FROM   jrtepipepart pp 
               JOIN jnameditem nmpp 
                 ON pp.oid = nmpp.oid 
               JOIN xcontainsnote xcn 
                 ON pp.oid = xcn.oidorigin 

        WHERE  gn.text <> '' 
               AND ( nmpps.itemname = 'Piping_New' 
                      OR nmpps.itemname = 'Piping_Modified/Tie_In' ) 
        --where gn.Text like '%000002A_TP08' AND (nmpps.ItemName = 'Piping_New' OR nmpps.ItemName = 'Piping_Modified/Tie_In')
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT hs.oid               AS OID, 
               nmhs.itemname        AS ItemName, 
               nmpl.itemname        AS Pipeline, 
               tn.trainnumber       AS TrainNumber, 
               uc.unitcode          AS UnitCode,                    
        FROM   jhgrsupport hs 
               JOIN jnameditem nmhs 
                 ON hs.oid = nmhs.oid                                       
        WHERE  gn.text <> '' 
               AND ( nmpps.itemname = 'Piping_New' 
                      OR nmpps.itemname = 'Piping_Modified/Tie_In' ))A     
SELECT pipeline, 
       unitcode, 
       designareanumber, 
       ( Stuff((SELECT Cast('; ' + nameofnote AS VARCHAR(max)) 
                FROM   @Pipeline p2 
                WHERE  ( p2.pipeline = p1.pipeline 
                         AND p2.unitcode = p1.unitcode 
                         AND p2.designareanumber = p1.designareanumber 
                         AND nameofnote NOT IN ( 'Note 1', '' ) ) 
                FOR xml path ('')), 1, 2, '') ) AS NameOfNote 
FROM   @Pipeline p1 
WHERE  nameofnote NOT IN ( 'Note 1', '' ) 
GROUP  BY pipeline, 
          unitcode, 
          designareanumber
```

When I run above query in OleDbDataAdapter it return 0 rows. I have tried adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` at start of the query but not working. I have increased set-timeout property.

Comment: Are you sure you connecting to the correct database? If you have multiple databases, I would say you are likely pointing to the wrong one. That is usally the issue. 

Could also be that the query is not identical between what you have in SQL, and what you are trying to execute.

You need to provide more code for anyone to give you an accurate response.

Comment: Database and everything correct because same other query runs perfectly. I think issue because of there are multiple operations performed in single query. First create table then insert value then select. So, I think query return result before execute last select.

Comment: SSMS doesn't use OleDb under the hood.  Try `System.Data.SqlClient`.  And show your code.

Comment: do you see this being requested in SQL Profiler? Also, can you share your .net code.  In addition to this when you debug this up to the call, is the connection string and any other properties correct

Comment: That query is not syntactically valid - there are no tables with the name or alias `gn` or `nmpps` within the derived table named `A` (in the first <insert / select> statement). Same goes for the second part of that union. So you're just making up things at this point. And the structure of the code you were given is overly complicated and does not need to involve a table variable. It could all be done as a single select statement.

Comment: i have actually faced the same issue, query returning data from ssms but not form entity framework

Answer (score 0):

Removed `USE testdb`, added `SET NOCOUNT ON` and added database name before table names resolved this issue.